# How can I change my calls to Firestore to make less read requests?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have 60 documents in my Firestore, every time I refresh the page it is reading 60 times, how can I change my calls so that 1 call is made to get total? With my project expanding the read requests will only increase and will start to get costly for me.

```
  function getAllJobs(){
       var docRef = db.collection("jobs");
       var totJobs  = 0;
       //Reading Record from firestore
    
         docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
         querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
           if(doc.data()['jobstatus']=="Completed"){
             totJobs = totJobs+1;
           }
             // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
         });
         $('#totJobs').append('<h3>'+totJobs+'</h3>');
         $('#totlink').append('<a href="../jobs/" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>');
      });
     }
    
     function getUnallocated(){
       var docRef = db.collection("jobs");
       var totUnallocated  = 0;
       //Reading Record from firestore
    
         docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
         querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          if(doc.data()['jobstatus']=="Unallocated"){
           totUnallocated = totUnallocated+1;
         }
             // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            // console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
         });
         $('#totUnallocated').append('<h3>'+totUnallocated+'</h3>');
         $('#unallocatedlink').append('<a href="../unallocated/" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>');
       });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `get()`, you are going to incur the cost of reads necessary to fulfill that query.  There is no way to reduce that cost - a read is always a read.

If you want to avoid the cost of a read from the server, you could try to query the local persistence layer using the instruction in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#get_offline_data).  Either that or you can perform your own local caching.  In either case, you will need to figure out if the local data is sufficient for your query, otherwise query the server again. This is usually not a straightforward process.